# How can I resend the commerce email from the admin orders screen?

Tags: commerce

Is there any way of allowing site admins to resend the default order email that commerce provides to the user after a completed order?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since I was using the commerce email module, it was a pretty easy setup to use a rules component and then add it to my /admin/commerce/orders vbo view.

```
{ "rules_resend_order_email_to_customer" : {
    "LABEL" : "Resend order email to customer",
    "PLUGIN" : "action set",
    "REQUIRES" : [ "variable_email" ],
    "USES VARIABLES" : { "commerce_order" : { "label" : "Commerce Order", "type" : "commerce_order" } },
    "ACTION SET" : [
      { "variable_email_mail" : {
          "to" : [ "commerce-order:mail" ],
          "variable" : "commerce_email_order_[mail_part]",
          "language" : "default"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: This is similar to the solution I used. I also created a custom Message type to send a separate admin order confirmation on order completion, and used a version of the code above to provide a VBO option to resend the admin order email. Came in handy on a customer site when their fulfilment house wasn't receiving the order emails and the client didn't want them to be logging in to view the orders online.

Comment: Thanks, just what I needed. Upvote.

Answer (score 0):

No, there's no such functionality.

Such functionality could be implemented on top of [Commerce Message](http://drupal.org/project/commerce_message) (since it can save sent messages into entities, allowing them to be resent later). Will require someone to code it and submit a patch.

Comment: Thanks for following up @Bojan Zivanovic. How about a way of using vbo and rules component? I have vbo running on my admin/commerce/orders screen. Select one or more orders, choose "resend order email"...?

Comment: Yeah, that could work.
Technically, it would be generating a new email, not resending the one from checkout time, but in practice it shouldn't have a difference.

Let me know if you get stuck on any one the steps.

Comment: Cool. @Bojan Zivanovic unfortunately I am stuck on the fist step :), the component. I dont know which type of component and what to act on. Thoughts?

Comment: I managed to figure it out and posted my answer. Thanks @Bojan Zivanovic